# LoadRunner version for 32-bit processor

Tags: version, loadrunner

I came to know that latest versions of HP LoadRunner will not work on 32-bit processors, when tried to install 12.60 version in my machine.
Can someone please tell me where to download an older version like 11.52 for me to work on the tool. In micro focus, there is only 12.60 version.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Its that that it will not work on 32-bit processors, but 32-bit processors are not supported (i.e. we didn't test on them and support will not help you if you get into trouble). if you feel you MUST install on a 32-bit OS it might still work.